# how application handle exception in try catch in disassembly

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, debugging, disassembly

Hi 
I am debugging such a program that call win32 api RaiseException().
I want to know how can i handle it manually not by debugger.

Tanx

Comment: i m an Amateur on programing.if i know something i will share on answers

Comment: You still should go through questions you have asked earlier, and accept the best/correct answer. From the FAQ: "When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer."

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use a debugger?

Answer (score 2):

Try reading up on [Structured Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then check out Matt Pietrek's article: [A Crash Course on the Depths of Win32™ Structured Exception Handling](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx).